# Can you create a linked server from SQL Server (any version) to a SQL Server CE (3.5) database?

Tags: sql-server-ce, linked-server

We've purchased a tool from Redgate called SQL Data Compare.  I use it mainly for testing purposes to prove that my application is making the modifications to the database that I think it is, and not making any other changes.

My current application has both "online" and "offline" editing.  In online mode you are working directly with a SQL Server, and in offline mode you are working with a subset of the tables in a SQL CE (3.5) file.

Anyway, the SQL Data Compare tool doesn't support SQLCE, so I was hoping I could create a linked server to the SQLCE database and create a SQL Server database that mirrors the CE database through views, and that would let me do my testing.

So, I can't figure out how to create a linked server to a SQLCE database.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  I think if I were in your position at this point, I would write a little program (I think SSIS can do it) which could transfer the contents of your SQL CE database over to your SQL Server database, and then run SQL Data Compare.  :(